# Identify records repeating within a set time frame since their first creation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to figure out a query that could work for finding records that repeat within a pre-defined time frame after first beeing created.

Let’s say for example I want to identify customers who place a second order within 1 month from their last purchase.

In the following example, Tom and Jeff are both repeating customers. But only Jeff meets the criteria of placing the second order within a month:

```
Record Customer     Date
1      Tom          6/26/2018
2      Carly        6/31/2018
3      Jeff         7/1/2018
4      Jeff         7/20/2018
5      Tom          8/3/2018
```

I’m trying to figure this out without defining actual dates, since i want the start date to be set by the first time the record was found in the table.

Is there a way for SQL to do this?

Note: please let me know if need to specify, English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it, one of possible methods is a sefl join. 
The below query lists customers who had more than 1 purchases within 1 month, lists a date of the oldest purchase, a count, and a date of the last purchase within this period:

```
SELECT t1.Customer, min(t1.date), count(*), max(t2.date) 
FROM tablename t1
JOIN tablename t2 ON t2.date >= t1.date AND t2.date < t1.date + interval '1' month
GROUP BY t1.Customer
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Record] int, [Customer] varchar(5), [Date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Record], [Customer], [Date])
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', '2018-06-26 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'Carly', '2018-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'Jeff', '2018-07-01 00:00:00'),
    (4, 'Jeff', '2018-07-20 00:00:00'),
    (5, 'Jeff', '2018-07-23 00:00:00'),
    (6, 'Tom', '2018-08-03 00:00:00')
;
```

---

```
select Customer,count(1) OrderCount from (
  select distinct T1.* 
  from Table1 T1
  left join Table1 T2 on 
    T1.Record <> T2.Record
    and T1.Customer = T2.Customer 
    and DATEDIFF ( month , T1.[Date] , T2.[Date] ) =0 
  where T2.Record is not null
) T
group by Customer;
```

---

```
| Customer | OrderCount |
|----------|------------|
|     Jeff |          3 |
```

[Demo SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d7c07/4/0)

---

Hope It help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use *Windows function* with *CTE* Query to make **RowNumber**

then self join CTE query compare month difference between first row and second row .

look like this.

```
;with cte as(
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by Customer ORDER BY Record) rn
  FROM T 
)
select t1.Customer
from 
cte t1 left join cte t2
ON t1.Record < t2.Record and t1.Customer = t2.Customer 
and t1.rn = 1 and t2.rn = 2
where DATEDIFF( month , t1.[Date] , t2.[Date])=0
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/01e3b/7

Answer (score 0):

I believe a combination of LAG & DATEADD & IIF (or CASE) can also be used for this.
Then you get the 1 or 0 for each customer date compared to the previous customer date.

Which can then be summed up.

It's an alternative that doesn't require a self-join.

```
declare @Table1 table (ID int identity(1,1) primary key, Customer varchar(5), [Date] datetime);

INSERT INTO @Table1 ([Date],Customer) VALUES
('2018-06-26','Tom'),
('2018-07-02','Carly'),
('2018-07-01','Jeff'),
('2018-07-20','Jeff'),
('2018-07-23','Jeff'),
('2018-08-03','Tom');

SELECT Customer, SUM(PreviousDateWithinMonth) as TotalWithinMonth
FROM
(
    SELECT * , IIF(DATEADD(month,1,lag([Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY [Date])) >= [Date],1,0) AS PreviousDateWithinMonth
    FROM @Table1 t1
) q
GROUP BY Customer
HAVING SUM(PreviousDateWithinMonth) > 0
ORDER BY TotalWithinMonth DESC;
```